# How compile a loadable kernel module without recompiling kernel

Tags: kernel, modules

I have read quite a bit about how to compile a kernel module on (and for) the Raspberry Pi, but I'm still not quite able to figure out why it's not working.  I have been able to build the module, but it reports `Invalid module format` when I try to `insmod` the result.  Here is the process I followed.  First, as root under `/root` I executed the following shell script:

## getKernel.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
FIRMWARE_HASH=$(zgrep "* firmware as of" /usr/share/doc/raspberrypi-bootloader/changelog.Debian.gz | head -1 | awk '{ print $5 }')
KERNEL_HASH=$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/$FIRMWARE_HASH/extra/git_hash -O -)
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux 
cd linux
git checkout $KERNEL_HASH
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/$FIRMWARE_HASH/extra/Module.symvers 
zcat /proc/config.gz >.config
make oldconfig
make modules_prepare
ln -s /root/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

The first few lines are from http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/Compiling-a-kernel-module-for-the-raspberry-pi-2

The rest I wrote to automate more of the process. Once all of that runs successfully, I have the source that should exactly match the running kernel, the configuration to match and a symlink.  There were some redirects from the github web location (apparently it's now https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ ) but no actual errors.

Then I become the default `pi` user and in a directory named `/home/pi/projects/lkm` I have this source code for a very simple toy module:

## hello.c

```c
#include <linux/init.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Do-nothing test driver");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");

static int __init hello_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world.\n");
   return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Finally, I build the module with this Makefile

## Makefile

```
MODSRC=/home/pi/projects/lkm
obj-m+=hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=${MODSRC} modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=${MODSRC} clean
```

Finally, I attempt to load the module:

```
sudo insmod hello.ko
```

The result, however, is disappointing:

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello.ko: Invalid module format

### Possibly relevant details

I'm using the currently latest `jessie` version of Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi2.

```
$ uname --kernel-release --kernel-version
4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to further troubleshoot this or fix it.  Any clues?

Comment: I compiled all my findings and experiences into a script, see https://github.com/x29a/kernel/blob/master/rpi/prepare.sh and the related blogpost https://blog.chris007.de/compiling-a-kernel-module-on-and-for-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, make sure you use the proper kernel headers. I assume that your kernel headers and source code are more updated than the kernel you're running.

Try to do an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` then reinstall the module. If the problem persists, triple check that your kernel headers match your current kernel, recompile again then try to install.

---

Note: I'm using Jessie.

**UPDATE:**
Run these as root.

```
# The usual update routine
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y

# Update the kernel!
rpi-update
```

You may need to reboot. After that, proceed with the commands below, still using the root account.

```
# Get rpi-source
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source

# Make it executable
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source

# Tell the update mechanism that this is the latest version of the script
/usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update

# Get the kernel files thingies.
rpi-source
```

If `rpi-source` throws a GCC error (something about a version mismatch), it's okay **as long as your current GCC version is higher**. Run `rpi-source --skip-gcc` instead of `rpi-source`

Then, proceed with your Hello World example. Create the folder and `cd` into it. Then, create the files.

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
```

---

### Files:

**hello.c**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int hello_init(void)
{
    pr_alert("Hello World :)\n");
    return 0;
}
void hello_exit(void)
{
    pr_alert("Goodbye World!\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

**Makefile** (case-sensitive?)

```
obj-m := hello.o
```

---

Now that you have your files, you can go ahead and run the usual Hello World build commands:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
insmod hello.ko
```

You should now check `dmesg`. The last line should print `Hello World :)` highlighted in red.

If you do, congratulations. You just made and installed a kernel module.

Now remove it using  `rmmod hello`. `dmesg` should now print `Goodbye World!` highlighted in red.

Sources: [1](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) [2](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) [3](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki/Examples-on-how-to-build-various-modules#hello-world-example)

Comment: @Edward Take note that this is the hello world example. I built your module, but I realized it's the same. The only difference is that your code does not have the red highlight.

Comment: @Edward In your case, I think following the instructions up until the `rpi-source` part is enough. You can try building yours from that point.

Answer (score 7):

There is a much simpler version here, tested on **jessie** and **stretch**.

`sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`

and then when your files are in place :

`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules`

**Example**

Create the `hello` directory, go inside and create the following files 
: `hello.c` and `Makefile`.

I **recommend** working as your normal user, **not root**, only `insmod`, `rmmod`, and `make modules_install` commands require root permissions, and the necessary `sudo` is shown in the following commands.

---

**hello.c** (unchanged, your file)

```
#include <linux/init.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Do-nothing test driver");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");

static int __init hello_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world.\n");
   return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

**Makefile** (changed)

```
obj-m+=hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean

modules_install: all
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install
    $(DEPMOD)
```

---

**Usage**

- Build : `make` (in the same directory as the Makefile)
- Test

  - Insert the module with `sudo insmod hello.ko`
  - Find `Hello World :)` in the output of `dmesg`
  - Remove the module with `sudo rmmod hello`
  - Find `Goodbye, world.` int the output of `dmesg`
- Install, when your module is working, `sudo make modules_install` will install the module where it belongs, so `modprobe` will work.

Comment: works very well for kernels installed by means of the 'raspberrypi-kernel' package. Contrary to that the description issued by 'pandalion98' refers to kernels  installed by means of 'rpi-update'. Both methods are mutually exclusive right?

Comment: I think this is a valid answer since OP (Edward) never talked about `rpi-update`, `rpi-update` was suggested in the pandalion98's answer

Comment: @sparkie At the time of posting, the kernel was still not integrated into Raspbian's `apt` repository, if I'm not mistaken. Updating the kernel meant running Hexxeh's `rpi-update` script. These days, updating `raspberrypi-kernel` or running `rpi-update` do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: As for `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, it usually installs mismatched kernel headers, from experience (the headers tend to be a newer version than the kernel), hence why I opted to "go manual".

Comment: there appears to be some difference between 'raspberrypi-kernel' and 'rpi-update': the one results in '4.9.66+' the other in '4.9.59+' at this moment. So I think we still have to handle both build procedures separately

Comment: @sparkie I did want to mention that in my previous comment, but decided to edit it out. `rpi-update` pulls in the bleeding-edge build, while the apt package provides a more stable version. Refer to here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/updating.md

Comment: right, that's what I think. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: It's really a shame that there are two incompatible ways of updating the kernel

Answer (score 2):

in `getKernel.sh` file add

```
sudo modprobe configs
```

before

```
zcat /proc/config.gz >.config
```

(now in default rpi image /proc/config.gz not exist)