# Getting kernel headers for raspberry pi 2

Tags: kernel, v4l2

I'm attempting to create a virtual video device on raspberry pi 2 using v4l2loopback and prior installation of the v4l2loopback on their [website](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) in the Dependencies section they say that the kernel headers must be the same as the kernel where you want to use the module but on raspberry 2 it's not the same. The kernel installed is 4.1.17-v7+ and there are no headers with the same version e available on the repository so I need to get it by myself. I came across [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=17666) thread but I don't know how to get the linux headers 4.1.17-v7 from //github.com/raspberrypi/linux/ to follow **shig** instructions and see what happens. Could you show me how to install linux headers 4.1.17-v7 on raspberry 2?

PS: Doing the following commands, I can install the v4l2loopback-dkms but when I do the modprobe command it says that the module v4l2loopback wasn't found.

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** You can also search for the headers [here](https://www.niksula.hut.fi/~mhiienka/Rpi/linux-headers-rpi/). Raspberry Pi 2's kernel header will have "-v7" in it. Download the appropriate version and run `sudo dpkg -i [package]`

1. You could pull the kernel source code for *4.1.17-v7*, `cd` into it, then run `make_headers`
2. You could:

   ```
   # Get rpi-source
   sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source

   # Make it executable
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source

   # Tell the update mechanism that this is the latest version of the script
   /usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update

   # Get the kernel files thingies.
   rpi-source
   ```

   If `rpi-source` throws a GCC error (something about a version mismatch), it's okay as long as your current GCC version is higher. Run `rpi-source --skip-gcc` instead of `rpi-source`

   The above instruction installs the whole kernel source code, not just the headers. After your current project, you could build a kernel with a custom splash screen maybe?

<sub>[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40419/24224)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The following should install all needed to compile linux modules:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```