# Unable to 'make' basic kernel module

Tags: kernel, make

I'm trying to write a basic kernel module for my Raspberry Pi V4 Model B.

I tried to follow the steps at [puddleofcode.com](https://puddleofcode.com/story/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-kernel-module-raspbery-pi-and-led-matrix) and [How compile a loadable kernel module without recompiling kernel](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39845/how-compile-a-loadable-kernel-module-without-recompiling-kernel).

```
obj-m := pix_mod.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

However, regardless of which version of the `Makefile` I'm using, I'm always getting this error:

```
Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I'm not a `make` user, so I have no idea what this error message means.

The only thing I'm suspecting is that the error is somewhere on line 4.

Comment: what research have you done? ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=makefile+missing+separator&ia=qa

Comment: your question does not belong here ... it is a Linux question, not a Raspberry Pi specific question

Comment: @jsotola Actually, it belongs here. Because I'm trying to get a kernel module working _for_ the raspberry pi. It's not a Linux question.

Comment: And @jsotola I'm not going to ''make'' research on an error message that is so obscure like this one `Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. The issue was that the indentation was wrong (spaces instead of tabs).

Comment: The error message is unhelpful and obscure. I was hoping someone with actual knowledge about `make` could answer my question.

Comment: why is it that the first hit in the link I posted in a comment literally describes the solution that you posted?

Comment: `I'm trying to get a kernel module working for the raspberry pi` ... no ... you are trying to compile a kernel module for Linux

Comment: You haven't read correctly. I said `I'm not going to ''make'' research on an error message [...]`

Comment: why should anyone spend time answering a question that you are unwilling to answer yourself?

Comment: You are an idiot. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask oh my god.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong... my understanding is that you do not wish to spend time researching the error on the internet ... my comment comes from that understanding

Comment: Yes, because that error isn't saying anything particularly useful. I'm not familiar with the syntax of `Makefile` files. Also, you never know what kind of crooked version of a tool you might have installed on your system. I don't trust the software installed on my pi, not to the level I would on a "normal" machine ; let me give you an example (even though this is totally out of scope): if you login into your raspi for the first time, you have to wait a couple seconds before it even accepts the **valid default credentials**.

Comment: On another (raspberry pi) system I got `Makefile:4: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.` this is a much more useful error message, and it would have stopped me from asking that question here - but `make` decided to bail out with a cryptic error message instead..

Answer (score -1):

Turned out `make` isn't happy with 4 spaces as indentation (duh, I just copied the Makefile from these sites).

Anyway, replacing the 4 spaces with 1 tab fixed the issue.

(I can't post the correct Makefile syntax here, because it will get replaced with spaces)